# paypal buy now button and shipping address

Tags: php, paypal

I want to setup a simple shopping cart using PHP, only 2 items, I am planning to use paypal buynow button for this, but what about the shipping address details ?, should I collect those details from my site or paypal has such an option so that users can enter shipping address ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you will be using Paypal's Website Payment Standard for payment.

This service supports insertion of [HTML variables](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HI0709B) (e.g.: address1, address2, country, etc.), to automatically populate Paypal's Checkout pages.